# How to form Rails Mongo Id Include Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid5

I am using

- MongoId 5.4
- Rails 4.2

Want to perform join operation and retrieve the result based on criteria.

**Band Table**

```
    has_many :band_histories, dependent: :destroy
    field :name, type: String
    field :description, type: String
```

**Band History**

```
   belongs_to :band, foreign_key: :band_id
   field :subject, type: String
   field :status, type: String
```

I want to add make a search on Band history where band name is 'Star band'

**Normal Query Can be Made like**

```
BandHistory.where(: band_id.in => Band.where(name: 'Star band').pluck(:id))
```

Trying to use includes to make it more generic

```
BandHistory.includes(:band).where('bands.name':'Star band').count
```

Above include and where clause is not returning any result

Can anyone help where i am doing wrong